# GET http://localhost:5000/user net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux

So I am creating a React redux crud application and I am using JSON and Axios. I set up the .env and db.json and edited the package.json file.
But after running all of that I get the following error (screenshots), also I defined that the server uses port 5000 but in the resources it gives me localhost 3000, I have no idea why its doing that

.env

```
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:5000/user
```

db.json

```
{
"user": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Leanne Graham",
       "username": "Bret",
       "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
       "address": {
         "street": "Kulas Light",
         "suite": "Apt. 556",
         "city": "Gwenborough",
         "zipcode": "92998-3874",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-37.3159",
           "lng": "81.1496"
         }
       },
       "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
       "website": "hildegard.org",
       "company": {
         "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
         "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
         "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Ervin Howell",
       "username": "Antonette",
       "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
       "address": {
         "street": "Victor Plains",
         "suite": "Suite 879",
         "city": "Wisokyburgh",
         "zipcode": "90566-7771",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-43.9509",
           "lng": "-34.4618"
         }
       },
       "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
       "website": "anastasia.net",
       "company": {
         "name": "Deckow-Crist",
         "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
         "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "name": "Clementine Bauch",
       "username": "Samantha",
       "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
       "address": {
         "street": "Douglas Extension",
         "suite": "Suite 847",
         "city": "McKenziehaven",
         "zipcode": "59590-4157",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-68.6102",
           "lng": "-47.0653"
         }
       },
       "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
       "website": "ramiro.info",
       "company": {
         "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
         "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
         "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 4,
       "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
       "username": "Karianne",
       "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
       "address": {
         "street": "Hoeger Mall",
         "suite": "Apt. 692",
         "city": "South Elvis",
         "zipcode": "53919-4257",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "29.4572",
           "lng": "-164.2990"
         }
       },
       "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
       "website": "kale.biz",
       "company": {
         "name": "Robel-Corkery",
         "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
         "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 5,
       "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
       "username": "Kamren",
       "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
       "address": {
         "street": "Skiles Walks",
         "suite": "Suite 351",
         "city": "Roscoeview",
         "zipcode": "33263",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-31.8129",
           "lng": "62.5342"
         }
       },
       "phone": "(254)954-1289",
       "website": "demarco.info",
       "company": {
         "name": "Keebler LLC",
         "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
         "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 6,
       "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
       "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
       "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
       "address": {
         "street": "Norberto Crossing",
         "suite": "Apt. 950",
         "city": "South Christy",
         "zipcode": "23505-1337",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-71.4197",
           "lng": "71.7478"
         }
       },
       "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
       "website": "ola.org",
       "company": {
         "name": "Considine-Lockman",
         "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
         "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 7,
       "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
       "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
       "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
       "address": {
         "street": "Rex Trail",
         "suite": "Suite 280",
         "city": "Howemouth",
         "zipcode": "58804-1099",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "24.8918",
           "lng": "21.8984"
         }
       },
       "phone": "210.067.6132",
       "website": "elvis.io",
       "company": {
         "name": "Johns Group",
         "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
         "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 8,
       "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
       "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
       "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
       "address": {
         "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
         "suite": "Suite 729",
         "city": "Aliyaview",
         "zipcode": "45169",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-14.3990",
           "lng": "-120.7677"
         }
       },
       "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
       "website": "jacynthe.com",
       "company": {
         "name": "Abernathy Group",
         "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
         "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 9,
       "name": "Glenna Reichert",
       "username": "Delphine",
       "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
       "address": {
         "street": "Dayna Park",
         "suite": "Suite 449",
         "city": "Bartholomebury",
         "zipcode": "76495-3109",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "24.6463",
           "lng": "-168.8889"
         }
       },
       "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
       "website": "conrad.com",
       "company": {
         "name": "Yost and Sons",
         "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
         "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
       }
     },
     {
       "id": 10,
       "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
       "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
       "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
       "address": {
         "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
         "suite": "Suite 198",
         "city": "Lebsackbury",
         "zipcode": "31428-2261",
         "geo": {
           "lat": "-38.2386",
           "lng": "57.2232"
         }
       },
       "phone": "024-648-3804",
       "website": "ambrose.net",
       "company": {
         "name": "Hoeger LLC",
         "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
         "bs": "target end-to-end models"
       }
     }
   ]
```

}

package.json

```
enter code "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000"
```

},

Actions.js

```
import * as actions from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios'

const getUsers = (users) => ({
type: actions.GET_USERS,
payload: users,
})

export const loadUsers = () => {
return function (dispatch) {
    axios
    .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}`)
    .then((resp) => {
        console.log("resp", resp);
        dispatch(getUsers(resp.data))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

}

Reducer.js

```
import * as actions from './actionTypes'

 const initialState = {
 users: [],
 user: {},
 loading: true,
}

const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
    case actions.GET_USERS: {
        return {
            ...state,
            users: action.payload,
            loading: false
        }
    }
    default:
        return state;
  }
 }

 export default usersReducer;
```

Home.js code snippet

```
const Home = () => {
let dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUsers());
}, [dispatch])
```

[image]

json-server --watch db.json
[image]

Comment: connection refused means that there is nothing listening on that port on that ip or the firewall is blocking it

Comment: Yeah it was my fault, my first time working with JSON... i had to start the npm run server in a different terminal. Thanks for the help

Comment: If cant flag your comment as correct

Comment: No worries, it's only a comment :) you can't accept it or give a credit anyway. But I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to start the npm run server in a different terminal and then npm start on a second terminal aka inside of VSC